# Monero sync too too slow

Tags: monerod, synchronization

I'm syncing monero for the first time.
I have an SSD on my syncing PC.
I left all day syncing plus all night.
I still got 253624 blocks to sync, and letting it all night only synced 400 blocks. This will take forever.
From `monerod` I seem to only get messages like this:

> 2017-06-05 12:29:51.590   [P2P4]  INFO    global  src/cryptonote_protocol/cryptonote_protocol_handler.inl:293 [93.230.40.55:18080 OUT] Sync data returned a new top block candidate: 1072218 -> 1325842 [Your node is 253624 blocks (352 days) behind] 
>   SYNCHRONIZATION started

What should I do too get fully synced while I'm still alive?

Comment: I'm thinking of syncing by importing the blockchain.raw. Having already started the sync, can I still do this? Do you think it will take less time?

Comment: Not sure, if your CPU is the bottleneck it may not make a difference. On my laptop it takes about 8h. Which CPU do you have? Also be sure you're running latest ver. as there was a speedup to RCT verification

Comment: I have a quadcore 2.8GHz with 8GB RAM @JollyMort

Comment: What ports do I need to open on my firewall and router? I currently only have 18080 open

Comment: Strange, you should have better times. Newer generation? I thing AES-NI CPU support is relevant. It can be any of: CPU, HDD, network bandwidth. Are you running v0.10.3.1? Anyways, that's the port. When typing `status` into `monerod` you'll see something like `Height: 1326055/1326055 (100.0%) on mainnet, not mining, net hash 83.51 MH/s, v5, up to date, 8(out)+0(in) connections, uptime 0d 0h 10m 17s`. 8(out) means I initiated 8 connections, and 0(in) means there are no connections initiated by peers as my firewall blocks incoming connections. With only 8 peers, it's enough for me.

Comment: Its my ISP (Vodafone) that is cutting my internet. I'm only getting 120kbps until the end of the month because of high traffic downloads

Comment: oh there's your problem, in that case you're probably better off using the .raw file:
https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/2743/since-monerod-through-tor-is-slower-on-whonix-would-importing-the-raw-be-fas

Howto: https://monero.stackexchange.com/a/2762/57

Answer (score 5):

These are the usual suspects for slow sync:

- **CPU speed** (for block verification). Nothing you can do here other than upgrade CPU or wait for some software optimization but I don't believe there can be any major improvements anymore.
- **HDD/SSD speed** (big slowdown for HDDs, as you have to read / write the blockchain somewhere). Same "solution" as above.
- **Network bandwidth**. If your connection is sucky, you might get better results [reducing sync size](https://monero.stackexchange.com/a/4497/57) or [importing from .raw file](https://monero.stackexchange.com/a/2762/57).
- **Outdated software** (sometimes optimizations are rolled out into latest versions). It's good practice in general to have updated software, and sometimes they'll come with a performance boost, too!

From your comments, it seems that network bandwidth is the culprit. Try the .raw method :)